# Some Arrows in the package tikzcd

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

Here is the diagram codes and the output of it. I got the codes from the `tikzcd` documentation but when I want to add some extra arrow, it gives a mistake. How can I add an UP ARROW from "ij-S-open" and a DOWN ARROW from "ij-P-open"?

```
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny] 
 & ij-S-O \ar[dr, Rightarrow] \ar[drr, Rightarrow, bend left=20]
 &

 &
[1.5em] \\
 ij-\alpha-open \ar[ur, Rightarrow] \ar[dr, Rightarrow]
 &

 &
 SP-O \ar[r, dashed]
 &
 ij-SP-SD \\
 &
 ij-P-O \ar[ur, Rightarrow]\ar[urr, Rightarrow, bend right=20]  
 &
&

 \end{tikzcd}
```

[image: arrows]

Comment: Unrelated: You should replace `open` with `\mathit{open}` for proper spacing.

Comment: Thank you so much @SandyG

Answer (score 1):

You need to first create a node to which the arrow can point. The minimal set up for this is `{}` which depicts an empty node.

Please note that blank lines inside a `tikzcd` environment will lead to compilation errors. The `[1.5em]` has no meaning there, hence I removed it.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny] 
 & {} & & \\
 & ij-S-O \ar[dr, Rightarrow] \ar[drr, Rightarrow, bend left=20] \ar[u]
 &
 & \\
 ij-\alpha-open \ar[ur, Rightarrow] \ar[dr, Rightarrow]
 &
 &
 SP-O \ar[r, dashed]
 &
 ij-SP-SD \\
 &
 ij-P-O \ar[ur, Rightarrow] \ar[urr, Rightarrow, bend right=20] \ar[d] 
 &
 & \\
 & {} & &
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am afraid of that I will die without learning this package, it is quite hard. Are there any guide book or something which explains easier? @JasperHabicht

Comment: Well, it is essentially a combination of Ti*k*Z and array logic. So, you should probably first make yourself comfortable with arrays (but you don't need too much detail here), and then dive into Ti*k*Z which has a very nice (but also very large) manual. If you know both good enough, mastering the `tikz-cd` package is not at all hard.

Comment: thank you so much for the information, I will bring on it @JasperHabicht